# The server returned status code '200' when status code '101' was expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, websokets

Реализовываю передачу сообщения по вебсокету. Есть `wss://localhost:44382/api/new`, который получает сообщения от `wss://localhost:44382/api/get`, который их отправляет. Вот фрагмент кода клиента, который отправляет данное сообщение. На этапе `ConnectAsync` вылетает эксепшн `The server returned status code '200' when status code '101' was expected.` В чем может быть проблема? никак не могу найти решение...

```
using (var socket = new ClientWebSocket())
            {
                var uri = new Uri("wss://localhost:44382/api/new");
                var cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource();
                await socket.ConnectAsync(uri, cts.Token);
                if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    ArraySegment<byte> bytesSend = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{message.Id}+{message.Text}+{message.SentTime}"));
                    await socket.SendAsync(bytesSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cts.Token);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Скорее всего сервер без TLS/SSL ожидает подключение, попробуйте поменять в адресе на `ws://`

Comment: с таким адресом страница долго думает и выдает Unable to connect to the remote server